# Multicolor border using CSS linear-gradient

Tags: css

I made a multicolor border :
https://codepen.io/Niavl/pen/vpmvmL

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.my-div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*border bottom*/

.my-div:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 45%, #87c846 45%, #87c846 60%, #e32b2d 60%, #e32b2d 70%, #ffc846 70%, #ffc846 95%, #847c6c 95%);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  hello
</div>
```

I use for that css linear-gradient.

It works but it is not clean especially on chrome: There is blur between 2 colors.

Any idea to make it cleaner ?

Comment: Why especially on Chrome?

Comment: because the pb is more visible on chrome than firefox : firefox>http://prntscr.com/hv2uet // Chrome>http://prntscr.com/hv2uls

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome...looks perfect

Comment: @Paulie_D I can see this issue in my Chrome `63.0.3239.84`

Comment: @Paulie_D : I have the same issue on opera... It is not perfect at all.

Comment: Hmmm looks fine in Chrome Version 64.0.3282.39 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: I have 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64 bits)